# Install Android SDK sources-30_r01.zip and platform-30_r03.zip manually (Windows 10)

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Android Studio SDK Manager cannot download https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-30_r01.zip or https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-30_r03.zip because of the company's SSL interception (it runs a scan on some files before it lets you download them). But I can manually download these files by putting the links in a browser and waiting for the scan to complete.

How can I make Android Studio SDK Manager install these zip files from disk, rather than trying to download them, on Windows 10? I have tried to find out on the internet but all of the answers are either out of date or do not quite apply to this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had SDK problem similar to yours. I followed the steps;

1. Download https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-30_r03.zip
2. Go to the directory
   **C:\Users\computer-name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms**
3. Unzip platform-30_r03.zip ( will create an android-11 folder)
4. Delete platform-30_r03.zip after file extraction is complete
5. Restart Android Studio

Comment: Hi, Any specific link to download Android 31 platform?